# WordPress Twenty Fourteen Theme Sidebar

Tags: css, sidebar, child-theme, theme-twenty-fourteen

The Twenty Fourteen theme was used to create the basis of my own child theme.  It's been pretty easy to override, but the left sidebar is proving difficult.

I don't want to remove the sidebar completely, but nothing I do in the CSS file allows me to get rid of the black bar.  Even removing the sidebar from a template file leaves an empty black strip where the sidebar used to be.

Has anyone found a way to peacefully override this without throwing out the whole system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sidebar is created in two different places:

- The black strip is created from `.site:before`, check line 3910 of style.css
- `#secondary` actually displays the sidebar information, check line 3923 of style.css

`.featured-content, .site-content, .site-main .widecolumn` provide left padding to the content area should you wish to dispose of that too.